# how to hide any page element with mvc2 validation raising in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to hide a span when the validation raised

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you mean when validation is unsuccessful. You can do something like

```
formQueryObj.submit(function () {
            var f = $(this).valid();
            if (f === true) {
                ...
                return true;
            }
            else{
                ...your hide span code like $('span#spanid').hide();
                return false;
        });
```